# How to create new local folder/directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I want to create new folder locally using javascript in firefox browser. Following piece of code I tried, but no sucess.

```
var dir = new Dir(rcDirUrl); //doesnt work
dir.create(dir.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0775);
```

Can anyone help out how to create directory in javascript.

Comment: From JavaScript in a web browser you don't have any access to the local client-side file system, for obvious security reasons. (Well there is limited access through the File-related APIs, but that's it.)

Comment: It's impossible to do within the browser, however if you want to use JavaScript, you can something like this:- https://electronjs.org/

Comment: Did you see `Dir` used in an example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

if you're executing the JS in the browser - you cannot do it. Browser-based JS doesn't have access to the hard drive at all. You won't open anything (unless file is provided through file selector in HTML) and you won't store anything.

If you're using Node.js, you can do it with `fs.mkdir()` or `fs.mkdirSync()` - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode

Comment: It's not impossible to create directories using client-side JavaScript, since some browsers support the [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/).